# Errror when selecting an action from Find Participants

Tags: civievent

From Find Participants, I get an error when selecting an action. Seems to be any action.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/fotgm080/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Task.php:130 Stack trace: #0 /home/fotgm080/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Task.php(78): CRM_Event_Form_Task::preProcessCommon(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Task_AddToGroup)) #1 /home/fotgm080/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Task/AddToGroup.php(71): CRM_Event_Form_Task->preProcess() #2 /home/fotgm080/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(543): CRM_Event_Form_Task_AddToGroup->preProcess() #3 /home/fotgm080/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm() #4 /home/fotgm080/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Task_AddToGroup), 'display') #5 /home/fotgm080/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/ in /home/fotgm080/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Task.php on line 130

I'm still on CiviCRM 4.7.24 on WordPress 5.1 so I expect the proper solution will involve upgrading, but I'd like to delay that till when I have time to do some testing.